# Static IP in dhcp server

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp

I have the following situation:

Home network DHCP server ranged : 192.168.1.2-99

I need to set up a static ip for a machine in: 192.168.1.91

I cant set it up from network adapter because this machines moves from Home network to office network.

Office network : 10.0.0.0/16 (assigned by DHCP server)

I dont have a router rule to assign IP based on mac address, i can access via telnet to router and use busybox to configure router.

Can i configure router to always assign an IP to a macadress? my router is a Huawei HG630.

Some help would be apreciated!

Comment: You could use a couple of `cmd` scripts to toggle static/dynamic IP

Comment: The Huawei HG630/HG630b xDSL routers are pretty locked down, with few advanced features to speak of, intended for simple home installations. They do not have the capability of Static DHCP assignments. What you are requesting is not possible with your current equipment, you need to find an alternative such as a second network USB network adapter or running a simple batch/cmd script depending on which network you are connected to, or getting a DSL modem/router with more feature support.

Comment: Im not the final user for that machine, scripts arent an option in my case. If for some reason script fails, connection could fail and this is not an option.

Comment: i have a Pirelli Discus DRG A125G free right know, could it be used?

Comment: @TomasBond Simple scripts don't usually fail ... any more than DHCP fails ...

Comment: @DavidPostill whats a valid script for enabling staticip in one network, and dynamic in all others? is it hard? not so experienced here.

Comment: @TomasBond Just provide 2 scripts `home.cmd` and `office.cmd`. Click on the correct script. There are many different ways to try and automate this but we are not a script writing service. It's not so easy that I can give you an immediate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your router does not support DHCP reservations (a quick check online indicates that it does not), then there is nothing you can do on the router to achieve what you are looking for. You would either need to purchase a router with additional features or come up with a creative solution to automate changing the network adapter settings.